# Searches for list occurrences but only with the first item

Tags: python

My code works kind of fine, but I don't understand why it only searches using the first item form searchList. This is the code I have:

```
def analyzeSequence(dnastring,searchList):
    empty = {}
    for item in searchList:
        if dnastring.count(item) > 1:
            position = dnastring.index(item)
            times = dnastring.count(item)
            new = position, times
            empty[item] = new
            return empty

seq = "ATGCGATGCTCATCTGCATGCTGA"
sList = ["CAT","GC"]
print(analyzeSequence(seq,sList))
```

It prints:

```
{'CAT': (10, 2)}
```

But I want it to print:

```
{'CAT': (10, 2), 'GC': (2, 4)}
```

Comment: It's not possible for this dictionary to ever have more than one value in it, since you `return` the dictionary immediately after putting a value into it. I suggest the line `return empty` should be unindented to outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not `return` at the first time you go in the `if`, return at the end only

```
def analyzeSequence(dnastring, searchList):
    values = {}
    for item in searchList:
        if dnastring.count(item) > 1:
            values[item] = dnastring.index(item), dnastring.count(item)
    return values
```

If you're interested, here is the dict comprehension way

```
def analyzeSequence(dna, searchList):
    return {item:(dna.index(item), dna.count(item)) for item in searchList if dna.count(item)>1}
```